# Significance of Room 203

Tags: fargo-tv

I've seen a couple movies/shows recently which featured events that happened in a hotel room, and it seems a little specific to be coincidental but it was room 203 in both cases. In particular Season 3 of Fargo and also a foreign film, Wild Goose Lake. Google seems to suggest it has something to do with the Freedom Writer, but that seems a little unlikely for a foreign film. Is it just a coincidence or is this some kind of easter egg?

Comment: Confirmation Bias?

Comment: Two cases out of the thousands of movies and TV shows that are made each year is pure coincidence.

Comment: Possibly suffering from 'random' numbers not being random when actually chosen by humans - an example of "23 enigma" perhaps. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Number_23